# My SQL Server password expires every 10 minutes

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wcf, azure-sql-database

Our app is connecting to database via user id and pwd mentioned in the connection string of `web.config` file. The pwd for the user expires every 15 minutes due to security policies.

How to create a new password for this user and also update it automatically in `web.config` file?

Comment: Needing a mechanism to accomplish that sounds less secure than not changing it.

Comment: Can you use a Managed Service Identity, instead of a username/password? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi